# Does OptaPlanner support optimizations and constraints on continuous variables?

Tags: optimization, rule-engine, constraint-programming, drools-planner, optaplanner

I'm reading contradictory things in the documentation.

On one hand, this passage seems to indicate that continuous planning variables are possible:

> A planning value range is the set of possible planning values for a
>   planning variable. This set can be a discrete (for example row 1, 2, 3
>   or 4) or continuous (for example any double between 0.0 and 1.0).

On the other hand, when defining a Planning Variable, you must specify a `ValueRangeProvider` annotation on a field to use for the value set:

> The Solution implementation has method which returns a Collection. Any
>   value from that Collection is a possible planning value for this
>   planning variable.

Both of these snippets are in the same section of the documentation (http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/latest/optaplanner-docs/html_single/#d0e2518)

So, which is it? Can I use a full `double` as my planning variable, or do I need to restrict its range to the values in a specific `Collection`?

Looking at the actual algorithms are provided, I don't see any that are actually suitable for optimizing continuous variables, so I doubt it's possible, but it'd be nice to have that clarified and made explicit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We're working towards fully supporting continuous variables. But **currently (in 6.0.0.CR2) it's not decently supported yet**.

Value ranges can indeed be continuous ranges, but the plumbing to actually use them isn't there yet. We have made good progress recently, see https://issues.jboss.org/browse/PLANNER-160.

Here's how it will work:
You 'll be able to use a `@ValueRangeProvider` annotation on a method that returns a `ValueRange` (instead of a `Collection`) too.

A `ValueRange` will be an interface supports selecting a random value, getting a size, ...
Out-of-the-box we will support `IntValueRange`, `DoubleValueRange`, `BigDecimalValueRange`, ...
(Implementation detail: we'll retro-fit those Collection-returning methods into a `CollectionValueRange`.)

Then the ValueSelector implementations will use that directly.

As for the suitability to optimize continuous variables:

- JIT random selection will be blazing fast and be very memory-efficient.
- If you have an NP-complete/NP-hard problem, then OptaPlanner will be a great match. If you have only continuous variables (and not a single discrete variable), then it's unlikely that your problem is NP-complete (unless your constraints counterprove that) and in that case you're better off with a custom, handmade, polynomial algorithm anyway (because it's not NP-complete, so there's an "easy" solution).