# OptaPlanner and implementation of continuous variables

Tags: java, optaplanner

Hi I am currently trying to implment an OptaPlanner solution, and I am having difficulty with the syntax for 2 of the planning variables. The values are continuous doubles of a range that is required to be set dynamically before the solution is solved.

I have looked at the following 2 sites and am having difficulty in seeing how they should be implemented.

https://issues.jboss.org/browse/PLANNER-160

[Does OptaPlanner support optimizations and constraints on continuous variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18343221/does-optaplanner-support-optimizations-and-constraints-on-continuous-variables)

My current solution is failing to provide a vaible soluition and I belive it is down to the way that I have set these values up.

```
@PlanningVariable(valueRangeProviderRefs = {"yPosRange"})
public double getYCenter()
```

Please can someone let me know how this should be implemented. 
The value of the range can be anything between 0 and n.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Continuous variables are supported since 6.1, not in 6.0. In [this docs section](http://www.optaplanner.org/community/droolsPlannerRenamed.html), see "4.3.5.2.4. ValueRangeFactory", such as `ValueRangeFactory.createdDoubleValueRange(...)`.